# Why does flutter return type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' of 'function result'?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I cannot understand why I cannot print the elements in the List.
And always it returns "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'function result'"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Generated App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFF2196f3),
        accentColor: const Color(0xFF2196f3),
        canvasColor: const Color(0xFFfafafa),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var items = [1,2,3];

  void main() {
    if (true) {
      print('hello, world!');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('SingleChildScrollView'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(''),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            print(items[i]);
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.touch_app),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if I changed to the Print part as String, it prints "I/chatty" and I don't know what it means.

```
I/flutter (13445): items[i]
I/chatty  (13445): uid=10155(com.example.flutterappse) Thread-2 identical 1 line
I/flutter (13445): items[i]
```

Please let me know the reason and how to fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: I copied your code and ran it, and there's absolutely no problem with it. I got the output as expected which is the ints on each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List` with the `int` data type.

```
List<int> items = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: it was really simple reason..Thank you! 

Do you know this reason about beloe as well? 

I/flutter (13445): items[i]

I/chatty  (13445): uid=10155(com.example.flutterappse) Thread-2 identical 1 line

I/flutter (13445): items[i]